# Key provider with Postgres and GWT

Tags: java, postgresql, gwt, gwt2, postgresql-9.1

For my GWT project,

I initially constructed a List and a *KEY_PROVIDER* to uniquely identify my records in the List. Now instead of List I have connected to the Postgres database and am wondering as to if I need to pass an object of the *ProvidesKey* to the database OR remove it completely when using a database.

**EARLIER**-

```
// Make a provider, connect the List with the provider!
final ListDataProvider<Contact> sortProvider = new ListDataProvider<Contact>(KEY_PROVIDER);
sortProvider.setList(CONTACTS);
```

**NOW**-

```
// Create a data provider.
MyDataProvider sortProvider = new MyDataProvider();
sortProvider.addDataDisplay(table);
```

I am not sure how it needs to be done now?

Do I need to pass-

```
MyDataProvider sortProvider = new MyDataProvider(KEY_PROVIDER);
```

instead?

What should be the best practice? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the `ProvidesKey` interface is only used on the client side (GWT) to identify your objects.  This is important for knowing which object in a list is selected and also for  manually selecting another row in your `CellTable`/`CellList`.

If you don't specify a `ProvidesKey` implementation the CellWidgets will use the equals function of your DTO's to check if they are equal or not. You might run into problems if the object itself changes. So it's always good practice to specify a `ProvidesKey` implementation and doesn't depend on whether you use a `ListDataProvider`, a `AsyncDataProvider` or a custom data provider.

BTW what is `MyDataProvider`in your example? Is it a subclass of `AsyncDataProvider`?

Comment: MyDataProvider extends AsyncDataProvider and implements AsyncCallBack

Comment: So, I can infer that ProvidesKey is used to identify the rows uniquely in the front-end and is independent of how the database is handling the records in the back-end and so both should be present for handling the data in the best possible manner.

Comment: Yes that's correct. You are probably using a Long/sequence in PostgreSQL as primary key. I guess you will have a Long field in your DTO's on the client side. You can use that field as a unique identifier together with ``ProvidesKey``.